# How to get JSON child Items from large JSON files

Tags: php, json

Here my code so far, but return null value:

```
for ($i=0 ; $i<1000; $i++){
                $link = $obj->results->address_components[$i];                  
                var_dump($link->long_name);                 
            }
```

Tried to get json object off child items like in this google maps JSON, for example`**long_name**` and `**short_name**`. I need this value and combined with another mysql query results. But my code above always return NULL on the browser.

```
    {
        "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            }
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ]
....
     }
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

UPDATE: Also tried something like this: `$lat = $obj->results[0]->address_components->long_name;`

Comment: Hint: "results" is an array, not an object. Therefore it doesn't directly have a field called "address_components"

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, let me try to surf around the web. Thank for the hint

Comment: Well what do you need to search? You already seem to know how to deal with an array because you're doing it with address_components. To get the first item from the results array, just use `$obj->results[0]->address_components[$i];` use a loop if there are more items and you need to process them all

Comment: P.s. why are you always looping to 1000 addresses? What if there are more or less than that? It would probably make more sense to just foreach over the address_components array, then it will process the exact number of entries which actually exist there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this could help you...

```
if(isset($obj->results[0])){
    foreach($obj->results[0]->address_components as $addressComponent){                  
        var_dump($addressComponent->long_name);                 
    }
}
```

Here we are first checking for a result and then looping over all address components of that result.

Please see the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on the `foreach` control structure to learn how this works in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this (if this is PHP)?

```
foreach($obj->results[0]->address_components as $link) {              
    var_dump($link->long_name);                 
}
```